# undefined reference to own library function

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, mingw, static-libraries

I'm using QT(5)-Creator with 2 projects, that compile both with MinGW my C++ programs under Windows 7. One project generates a static library, and the other is just there to verify that the library is alright.

**The error:**

When building the library no errors are generated and it creates successfully the static lib `MyClassName.a`.

In turn, when trying to import the library, I get error messages durring building/compilation:

```
undefined reference to 'MyClassName::MyClassName()'
undefined reference to 'MyClassName::MyClassFunction()'
```

**The files:**

here's the **main.cpp** of my *importer* project

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "MyClassName.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyClassName *mainThread = new MyClassName();
    mainThread->MyClassFunction();

    return a.exec();
}
```

and it's .pro file

```
QT       += core
QT       += widgets
QT       -= gui

TARGET = TESTerase
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
CONFIG   +=extserialport
CONFIG   +=staticlib

TEMPLATE = app

HEADERS += \
    MyClassName.h

SOURCES += main.cpp    

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/ -lMyClassName

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/release
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/release

unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/release/MyClassName.a
```

btw I've used QT-Creator's *include external library* function

**My guesses:**

- Since I'm able to [Strg+Click] the functions in the main, I assume the error is thrown by the Linker.
- It may also be a manner of importing/creating/using libraries too, since I just started with that topic.

Anyways searching the Internet about it usually just results in the hint, to use the same compiler for both projects - which shouldn't matter in my case (since I'm building both projects with the same Creator and the same settings).

Has anybody an idea?

Thanks for your support

Kind Regards

[Update for Bogdans request]
the new .pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-04-29T19:46:22
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core
QT       += widgets

QT       -= gui

TARGET = TESTerase

TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
CONFIG   +=extserialport

HEADERS += \
    MyClassName.h

SOURCES += main.cpp

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/ -lMyClassName



win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/release/ -lMyClassName
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/debug/ -lMyClassName
else:unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/ -lMyClassName

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/release
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/release

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/release/MyClassName.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/debug/MyClassName.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/release/MyClassName.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/debug/MyClassName.lib
else:unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/MyClassName.a
```

Answer (score 1):

Your .pro file defines library dependencies only for unix platform `unix:!macx:`. I suppose there should be also `win32` for Windows.

Comment: I changed for Linux + Windows. The error messages disappear but now there's this `:-1: Error: No rule to make target '<Path-to>/MyClassName-Release/debug/MyClassName.a', needed by 'debug\TESTerase.exe'.  Stop.`

Comment: @user3085931 Show me your new .pro file.

Comment: @user3085931 You added pre-build dependencies which are not defined. I suppose you've already built `libMyClassName.a`, thus only add `win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/ -lMyClassName'`

Comment: If I exclude the last 5 lines I get the error message `cannot find -lMyClassName` and `error: ld returned 1 exit status`. Btw I used the Qt-lLibrary-iImport-wizard again.

Comment: @user3085931 Are you sure you generated `libMyClassName.a`? The name and `lib` prefix is important here.

Comment: exactly with the same name. I wasn't so sure about generating the library for Windows, since I'm using MinGW (and it generates an `.a` file). So I assume if enabling looking for Windows files will end up in searching for libMyClassName.lib or libMyClassName.dll (I forgot which is static and which not)

Comment: @user3085931 And are you sure that the path `$$PWD/../MyClassName-Release` is correct? For `PRE_TARGETDEPS` you defined additional subdirectory release/debug (`$$PWD/../MyClassName-Release/release`). MinGW looks for .a file (-l<name> looks for lib<name>.a)

Comment: well .../debug is empty and if i comment these .../debug  lines then I again receive `cannot find -lMyClassName`. These lines are generated by the wizzard (especially the last 5 lines, when enabling the option `Windows` and `search library in the subdirectories "debug" and "release"` - I've freely translated that line from my language into english) but it wouldn't change if I'd set the absolute paths there

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem just now. Build was working fine on macOS/OSX but not on Windows with the same codebase.

It was caused by the fact I was not exporting my symbols, which is necessary on Windows.

Use `Q_DECL_EXPORT` on functions when building the lib.
And use `Q_DECL_IMPORT` when using the functions from the lib.

Example how to do this here: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application#Creating_a_shared_library

Solved the problem in my case, hope it helps!